# Scrapy spider not writing in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap items from a several pages of a website to a postgres database. I tried different codes but still doesn't work, my database still empty...

**How can I scrap items from pages of a website to my Postgres database ? 
What is wrong with my code ?**

I show you the latest version of the code :

**Myspider.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy, os, re, csv
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule, Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, MapCompose
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from AHOTU_V2.items import AhotuV2Item 

def url_lister():
    url_list = []
    page_count = 0
    while page_count < 10: 
        url = 'https://marathons.ahotu.fr/calendrier/?page=%s' %page_count
        url_list.append(url)
        page_count += 1 
    return url_list

class ListeCourse(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ListeCAP_Marathons_ahotu' 
    start_urls = url_lister()

    deals_list_xpath='//div[@class="list-group col-sm-12 top-buffer"]/a[@class="list-group-item calendar"]' 

    item_fields = AhotuV2Item()

    item_fields = {
        'nom_course': './/dl/dd[3]/text()',
        'localisation' :'.//dl/dd[2]/span[1]/text()',
    }


    def parse_item(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)

        # iterate over deals
        for deal in selector.xpath(self.deals_list_xpath):
            loader = ItemLoader(AhotuV2Item(), selector=deal)

            # define processors
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()

            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
                loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
            yield loader.load_item()
```

Comment: Any exception in logs? Is the pipeline code getting executed or not?

Comment: I added the terminal window. Yes the pipeline is executed, but it seems that the pages found are not scrapped...

Comment: I don't see any rule calling `parse_item` and seems to me you should be using Spider and not CrawlSpider

Comment: Yes thanks, that what I just realised !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any rule calling `parse_item`

You should be using `Spider` and not `CrawlSpider` for your class. Change

```
class ListeCourse(CrawlSpider):
```

to

```
class ListeCourse(Spider):
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours looking for solution, I just realised the method used was the wrong one, that's why the spider didn't work.

**MySpider.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import Spider
(...)

class ListeCourse(Spider):
(...)
```